# In solid Iron, what is the charge of the positive atom?

Tags: metal

I'm familiar with the sea model of metals. What I'm curious about is: exactly how many electrons are lost by the iron, to be absorbed into the sea of electrons? For a general metal, how many electrons are lost to the sea of electrons?

Thanks

Comment: I'm curious to know whether this aspect of the electron sea model can be quantified, and how well it correlates with the melting and boiling points of the pure substances.